# NSDate format and value strange behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];

myres.start_date = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"date"], [self.data objectForKey:@"start_time"]]];
    NSLog(@"Start date is %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"date"], [self.data objectForKey:@"start_time"]]);
    NSLog(@"Start date from NSDate is %@", myres.start_date);
    myres.end_date = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"date"], [self.data objectForKey:@"end_time"]]];
    NSLog(@"End date is %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"date"], [self.data objectForKey:@"end_time"]]);
    NSLog(@"End date from NSDate is %@", myres.end_date);
```

and the result I am getting is:

```
Start date is 2011-03-31 9:00:00
Start date from NSDate is 2011-03-31 16:00:00 +0000
End date is 2011-03-31 10:00:00
End date from NSDate is 2011-03-31 17:00:00 +0000
```

why is the result different?
I would like to have it so that when I call myres.start_date description, it gives me the same data as the string.

Comment: what is your start time and end time friend? from where you getting these ?

Comment: it's from a dictionary that I have... it's not relevant at this point.. my point is that if you use a NSDateFormatter to generate a NSDate from a NSString then you try to call description from this new NSDate... the resulted that would be different because of the timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is different because you are printing your `NSDate` instances using the generic `description` method, which doesn't match the output format you expect.

If you used `[df stringFromDate:myres.start_date]` you should get the same output.

Keep in mind that `NSDate` stores a *representation of time*, and there are *many* ways to print time and `description`'s way of printing time is fixed.

The only way to have `description` of `NSDate` return a string in the format you want is to override it with a category or use a subclass.

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how time is stored and displayed: your `NSDate` is storing the time parsed by `NSDateFormatter`, and it is in fact returning out the same *data* in its `description` method. It is just *displaying* it in a different form.

Comment: and how to fix it so both points to the same time?? I want my NSDate to have the same date as the NSDateFormatter

Comment: doing that prints null as the NSDate

Comment: I need so that printing out the description gives me the exact date and time as the string

Comment: I mean doing that will only give me a string.. I actually want to have a NSDate object which is the same time as I specified in the string.. it's not just for printing purpose

Comment: Your NSDate object has the same time as the string you specified (assuming the string you gave it was specifying time in the device's default timezone), it is just printing it in UTC time instead if your local time. Print it using the dateformatter you have setup and you should see the same output.

Comment: it's not about the printing, I have some other class which uses this NSDate description and doesn't care about NSDateFormatter

Comment: I don't undertand what you mean. Edit your question so your code examples are easier to read and your problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The date formatter takes the time zone into account. When you use the date directly, you just get it's description, which is apparently zulu time.