# Cannot convert properly string to date objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, date

this is my code:

```
- (NSArray *)getCurrentDayEvents {  
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/LL/YYYY"];

    [currentDate retain];
    NSString *todayStringDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];

    return [eventiArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(inizio CONTAINS[cd] %@)", todayStringDate] ];
}
```

I can convert date to string but if I add something like:

```
NSDate *temp = [dateFormat dateFromString: todayStringDate];
```

I get something like 2010-12-26 always...
I know I'm doing a step 2 times..

btw i printed currentdate and i got this value:

> 2011-11-17 23:00:00 +0000

Comment: try [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

Answer (score 1):

The result is different because you are printing your NSDate instances using the generic description method, which doesn't match the output format you expect.
The only way to have description of NSDate return a string in the format you want is to override it with a category or use a subclass.
[NSDate format and value strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509252/nsdate-format-and-value-strange-behavior)